# Constraint Layout Vertical Align Center

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, constraint-layout-chains

How to vertically align and center objects in constraint layout? It is possible to align vertically or horizontally but I have not found a way to center at the same time beside constraining the views between two gridlines.

Vertical Align Center:
[image]

It seems like centering is a huge problem with constraint layout which forces me to go back to relative layout for "centerInParent", "centerVertical", and "centerHorizontal".

I would like to create the layout boxed in red using constraint layout:
[image]

Unfortunately, the only way I found without using two gridlines is with nested Relative and LinearLayouts (which Constraint Layout was supposed to solve this exact scenario!).

Layout using Relative and Linear Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/user_points"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/stat_1_layout"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/divider_1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stat_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="10"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/textSecondaryDark"
            android:maxLines="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stat_detail_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Streak"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            android:textColor="@color/textSecondary"
            android:maxLines="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider_1"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/stat_2_layout"
        android:background="@drawable/linedivider"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/stat_2_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stat_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="243"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/textSecondaryDark"
            android:maxLines="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stat_detail_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Calories Burned"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            android:textColor="@color/textSecondary"
            android:maxLines="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider_2"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stat_2_layout"
        android:background="@drawable/linedivider"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/stat_3_layout"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/divider_2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stat_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="3200"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/textSecondaryDark"
            android:maxLines="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stat_detail_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Steps"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            android:textColor="@color/textSecondary"
            android:maxLines="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The real problem seems to be centering a view horizontally and vertically AND then placing views relative to that centered view. Constraint layout allows you to center align views but not set the center aligned view as an anchor for other views.

Comment: See the answer below, it's possible to set the center aligned view as an anchor for other views.

Comment: The Preview window (for Text view, not Design) in Android Studio dynamically shows changes made to an xml layout (for static data). It greatly helps with experimentation.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

It's possible to set the center aligned view as an anchor for other views. In the example below "@+id/stat_2" centered horizontally in parent and it serves as an anchor for other views in this layout.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stat_1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="10"
        android:textColor="#777"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/stat_2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/divider_1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stat_detail_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Streak"
        android:textColor="#777"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/stat_1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/stat_1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/stat_1" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider_1"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="#ccc"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/stat_2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/stat_2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/stat_detail_2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stat_2"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="243"
        android:textColor="#777"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stat_detail_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Calories Burned"
        android:textColor="#777"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/stat_2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/stat_2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/stat_2" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider_2"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:background="#ccc"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/stat_detail_2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/stat_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/stat_2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stat_3"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="3200"
        android:textColor="#777"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/stat_2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/divider_2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stat_detail_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Steps"
        android:textColor="#777"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/stat_3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/stat_3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/stat_3" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's how it works on smallest smartphone (3.7 480x800 Nexus One) vs largest smartphone (5.5 1440x2560 Pixel XL)

[image: Result view]

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for taking the time to answer this question. These answers have really helped me understand Constraint Layout a lot better. The reason I'm marking this answer as correct vs Ben P.'s answer is because this answer anchors the items to the center object. With this solution, I can now align the center object to any other location and the other objects will follow.

Comment: How is working with Constraint Layout in your experience Eugene Brusov? I find that Constraint Layout is A LOT more manual configurations than using Relative Layout/Linear Layout because of the lack of centering and distribution methods. Wish Google came up with a layout that truly merged together Relative Layout and Linear Layout instead of a XCode/Web Builder style WYSIWYG.

Comment: @RayLi Well, I really enjoy ConstraintLayout, my favorite features are possibility to flatten layout and to size views with aspect ratio. You can also find my answers to various questions related to ConstraintLayout https://stackoverflow.com/users/7158449/eugene-brusov. Keep up posting questions :-)

Comment: and keep answering them Mr. Constraint Layout Expert ;)

Comment: Hi @RayLi I tried the above code. But all content goes to top left. Any idea how to do that like Mr. Eugene Brusov template?

Comment: what if we have 2 views??

Answer (score 79):

If you have a `ConstraintLayout` with some size, and a child `View` with some smaller size, you can achieve centering by constraining the child's two edges to the same two edges of the parent. That is, you can write:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

or

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```

Because the view is smaller, these constraints are impossible. But `ConstraintLayout` will do the best it can, and each constraint will "pull" at the child view equally, thereby centering it.

This concept works with any target view, not just the parent.

### Update

Below is XML that achieves your desired UI with no nesting of views and no `Guideline`s (though guidelines are not inherently evil).

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#eee">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#777"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:text="10"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/divider1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#777"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="Streak"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/divider1"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider1"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:background="#ccc"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/title1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/title2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#777"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:text="243"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/divider1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/divider2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#777"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="Calories Burned"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/divider1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/divider2"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:background="#ccc"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/title2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/title3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#777"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:text="3200"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/divider2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#777"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="Steps"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/divider2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Doh, that would mean all I need to do to vertically align center items is create a View item with a fixed height and constrain the child items inside it! But using this method, I would not be able to center horizontally the middle box and set the position of the left and right boxes relative to the center box. If only there was a "center" function in constraint layout!

Comment: You can center the middle box horizontally using the above method and then set the other two boxes to match the parent and the middle box's edge.

Comment: @RayLi I've updated my answer with a layout that I believe accomplishes what you want.

Comment: +1, this was simple and effective. It does feel a little bit hacky, wish constraintLayout had a 'center' function.

Answer (score 30):

May be i did not fully understand the problem, but, centering all view inside a ConstraintLayout seems very simple. This is what I used:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center">
```

[image]

Last two lines did the trick!

Comment: And now if we want to have some other views which are not in the center of the screen, how to do that ?

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy You can add another layout.

Comment: This doesn't work if you want to center specific views and leave other views in specific spots. This centers everything

Answer (score 23):

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        style="@style/textViewBoldLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Welcome"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: Can you add some text that explains why this works? This is a code-only answer.

Comment: This is the simplest, IMO. It also works when centering items on a row. It is telling the system that you want the top to match AND the bottom to match relative to the same item, which forces it to take the center line.

Answer (score 16):

You can easily center multiple things by creating a chain.
It works both vertically and horizontally

[Link to official documentation about chains](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#Chains)

**Edit to answer comment** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_score"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="10"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/second_score"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/second_score"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/subtitle"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Subtitle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/first_score"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/second_score"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/first_score"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/first_score"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second_score"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="120sp"
        android:text="243"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/thrid_score"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/first_score"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/thrid_score"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3200"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/second_score"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/second_score"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/second_score"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: This code gives this result]

You have the horizontal chain : `first_score <=> second_score <=> third_score`.
`second_score` is centered vertically. The other scores are centered vertically according to it.

You can definitely create a vertical chain `first_score <=> subtitle` and center it according to `second_score`

Comment: I tried the chain method and it does not work. The chain is "controlled by attributes set on the first element of the chain (the "head" of the chain)". The chain head can only be set as the "left-most widget for horizontal chains, and the top-most widget for vertical chains". You CANNOT set the center item as a chain head which prevents centering vertically AND horizontally at the same time.

Comment: @RayLi I edited my answer to show you what i had in mind

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer and showing what you had in mind. This technique will be very useful!

Answer (score 9):

I also had a requirement something similar to it. I wanted to have a container in the center of the screen and inside the container there are many views. Following is the xml layout code. Here i'm using nested constraint layout to create container in the center of the screen.

```
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
    tools:context=".activities.AppInfoActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivClose"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_round_close_24"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivAppIcon"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/dead" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAppName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Birds Shooter Plane"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivAppIcon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAppVersion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Version : 1.0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAppName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDevelopedBy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="Developed by"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAppVersion" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDevelopedName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="K Pradeep Kumar Reddy"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvDevelopedBy" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvContact"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Contact : kpradeepkumarreddy@gmail.com"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvDevelopedName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCheckForUpdate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="@string/check_for_update"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvContact" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the screenshot of the layout
[image]

Other solution is to remove the nested constraint layout and add constraint_vertical_bias = 0.5 attribute to the top element in the center of layout. I think this is called as chaining of views.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
tools:context=".activities.AppInfoActivity">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/ivClose"
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:src="@drawable/ic_round_close_24"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/ivAppIcon"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/dead" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvAppName"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/app_display_name"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:textSize="30sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivAppIcon" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvAppVersion"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/version"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:textSize="12sp"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAppName" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvDevelopedBy"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
android:text="@string/developed_by"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:textSize="12sp"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAppVersion" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvDevelopedName"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:text="@string/developer_name"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:textSize="14sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvDevelopedBy" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvContact"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:text="@string/developer_email"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:textSize="12sp"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvDevelopedName" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvCheckForUpdate"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
android:text="@string/check_for_update"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:textSize="14sp"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvContact" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the screenshot of the layout
[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Two buttons one centered one below to the left of it]

Showing it graphically.

Centering on parent is done by constraining both sides to the parent.
You can the constrain additional objects off of the centered object.

Note.
 Each arrow represents a "app:layout_constraintXXX_toYYY=" attribute.
 (6 in the picture)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to align vertically and Item in the ConstraintLayout then you only need to add two properties

```
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

This will align the View vertically inside layout but If you want to show the item in the centre of the ConstraintLayout then you need to add two more properties

```
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

This will align your item centre in the ConstraintLayout.

Answer (score 0):

To center vertically, I use chains. In component tree, simply select the elements to center vertically and choose **Center vertically** from the menu. This will automatically create a chain: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/constraint-layout#11

[image: How it's done]